# Error compiling node for optware - libv8.a: could not read symbols: File in wrong format

Tags: linux, node.js, arm, v8

Getting this error cross compiling node.js for optware (slug) on Ubuntu 11.10.

/optware/cs05q1armel/builds/node/build/default/libv8.a(api.o): Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 3)
/optware/cs05q1armel/builds/node/build/default/libv8.a: could not read symbols: File in wrong format

Using flags  --without-snapshot --without-ssl --dest-cpu=arm for ./configure

arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ being correctly picked up as compiler, though maybe not for this lib?

Any pointers appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This problem is due to compiling XXXX.o on a different architecture
>   machine.  For instance, Sun workstations compile into SPARC machine code while
>   our LINUX workstations compile into Intel x86 code.  If you compile part of a
>   project on one type of architecture and then try to compile the rest of the
>   project on another type of architecture, when you go to make the final
>   executable the linker/loader will NOT be able to read one of the parts of the
>   project .o files to create an executable, thus the 
>   "could not read symbols: File in wrong format" error message.
>   If you change machine architectures, or even operating system versions, while
>   doing a project it is reasonable to clean/remove all the existing .o files
>   and re-create the whole project on the current machine you are sitting at.

from http://ugweb.cs.ualberta.ca/~rod/tutorials/error_messagesC.html in section "Errors That Elude Your Understanding"